# Select, or not select a field based on a value in the next field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

From a table like this (this is just for here):

```
p_add  | p_add_s | p_phone | p_phone_s | p_user_id //0 = show 1= Hide
Address| 0       | 12345   | 1         | 1
Addr   | 0       | 12345   | 1         | 2
```

How can I do a select like:

```
 select p_add (if p_add_s = 0), p_phone (if p_phone_s=0) from table where p_user_id=1
or
    select p_add, p_phone from table where p_user_id=1 (if p_add_s = 0) and (if p_phone_s = 0)
```

These are incorrect. I included them just so u can get an idea.

Actually I only need data if the value with _s is 0.

Can this be done using sql or it'll have to achieved using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the mysql IF syntax:

```
select if(p_add_s=0, p_add, 'Address Private'),  if(p_phone_s=0, p_phone, 'Phone Private') from myTable
```

If the condition is met, it returns the middle section, otherwise, the last one.

Alternately, based on your second query:

```
select p_add, p_phone from table where p_user_id=1 and p_add_s = 0 and p_phone_s = 0
```

Note that this will not return rows where *all* the conditions within the where clause are not met, so the if statement might work better.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p_add, p_phone from table where p_user_id=1 and p_add_s=0 and p_phone_s=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p_add FROM yourtable
WHERE p_user_id = 1
AND p_add_s = 0
AND p_phone_s = 0
```

Don't forget to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).